# Amazon EC2, failed to ssh due to ssh server not started

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I added a bad script in startup script, turned out this script is blocking and hence ubuntu instance can't boot up to ssh server and I can't ssh into it.   Is there a way for me to go to the server console (like from VGA port)? like go to single-user mode or safe mode and fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you start from scratch?

Comment: I ask this question because I don't want to start from scratch, that means I have to install all the packages!

Comment: see also: https://serverfault.com/q/170858/148275

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any way to obtain server console access or change boot modes on the EC2 instances...

I had the same issue sometime ago, and I ended up creating a temporary EC2 instance, mounting the root device from the original (failing) EC2 there, modifying the files, then reattaching the device and destroying the temporary instance. Note: you may end up paying more depending on which instance type you launch.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience. It maybe the only way I can solve this.